# How to fix "Error: Element type is invalid:.." error in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-markers

I am new to React Native and wanted to build an app that involved a Map the user could interact with. I've been loosely following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vILzRmEqGI&list=PLQWFhX-gwJbkETb0lfml7W8VvZb-Hc8oK&index=2) to see how to put cards on the map when you tap on a marker. I follow his code up to 15:55 (minus anything involving the search bar or "chips" under it - I don't need that). I keep running into:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MapScreen`.

This error is located at:
in AIRGoogleMap (created by MapView)
in MapView (created by MapScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
... (console continues with more places where this error is).

I looked on Google on how to fix the error and I learned more about default vs named exports. Thinking this was the issue, I took my "markers" array that was a named export from another file (export const markers) and just added it all into this file to see if that would fix it. It didn't work even though I have no imports from my own files. I then went back through the video slowly and commented out everything I didn't need until the timestamp 15:55, but that also didn't work. The same error persists.

This is my first post and I appreciate any help I can get! I hope my code isn't too bad lol! :)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Animated,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    Platform,
} from "react-native";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

const Images = [
    { image: require('../../../assets/images/marker.png') },
    //...
];

const markers = [
    {
        coordinate: {
            latitude: 32.7755,
            longitude: 96.8089,
        },
        title: "Reunion Tower",
        description: "Good views",
        image: Images[0].image,
        rating: 4,
        reviews: 99,
    },
    //... (4 other markers I am editing out)
];

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const CARD_HEIGHT = 220;
const CARD_WIDTH = width * 0.8;
const SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET = width * 0.1 - 10;

const MapScreen = () => {
    const initialMapState = {
        markers,
        region: {
            latitude: 22.62938671242907,
            longitude: 88.4354486029795,
            latitudeDelta: 0.04864195044303443,
            longitudeDelta: 0.040142817690068,
        },
    };

    const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialMapState);

    const _map = React.useRef(null);
    const _scrollView = React.useRef(null);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                ref={_map}
                initialRegion={state.region}
                style={styles.container}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            >
                {state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
                    return (
                        <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinate} onPress={(e) => onMarkerPress(e)}>
                            <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap]}>
                                <Animated.Image
                                    source={require('../../../assets/images/marker.png')}
                                    style={[styles.marker]}
                                    resizeMode="cover"
                                />
                            </Animated.View>
                        </MapView.Marker>
                    );
                })}
            </MapView>
            <Animated.ScrollView
                horizontal
                scrollEventThrottle={1}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={styles.scrollView}
            >
                {state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <View style={styles.card} key={index}>
                        <Image
                            source={marker.image}
                            style={styles.cardImage}
                            resizeMode="cover"
                        />
                        <View style={styles.textContent}>
                            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardtitle}>{marker.title}</Text>
                            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardDescription}>{marker.description}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </Animated.ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default MapScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: Would you mind removing the commented out code, and abbreviating the long arrays? The code should be a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the style hygiene! I took out all the comments and reduced the arrays. Is that better?

Comment: Did you have OnMarkerPress function added to your code?  
"const onMarkerPress = (event) => {
        // Handle the marker press event here
        console.log("Marker pressed!", event.nativeEvent);
        // You can add your logic for handling the marker press event
    };
"

Comment: The video I was following didn't have that set up before the cards started showing on the screen, so I commented it out. I only have the code that was up until the basic cards were shown on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue seems to be related to the usage of the `PROVIDER_GOOGLE` from `"react-native-maps"` library. This issue typically occurs when the library is not set up properly or some dependencies are missing.

To fix this issue, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have installed the required dependencies for `react-native-maps`. Run the following commands in your project directory:

```
npm install react-native-maps
npx pod-install
```

If you are using `yarn`, you can use `yarn add react-native-maps` instead of `npm install`.

2. After installing the package, you need to link it. Run the following command:

```
react-native link react-native-maps
```

3. Now, you should properly configure your Android and iOS projects for `react-native-maps`. Follow the setup guide for Android and iOS from the official documentation: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#installation
4. For iOS, make sure to provide the necessary permissions for accessing the user's location. Add the following lines to your `Info.plist` file:

```xml
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required to show nearby places.</string>
```

Replace the string with an appropriate message for your app's usage.

5. If you are using Android, make sure to add the necessary permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

6. After completing the setup, rebuild your project:

```
react-native run-android
react-native run-ios
```

If everything is set up correctly, the error should be resolved, and your Map screen should work as expected. Remember to have a physical device connected or an emulator running to test the map functionalities.

Comment: I am using React Native expo, so I cannot execute this command.